# User32.dll mouse events

Tags: c#, mouse

I'm looking at a cursor control class that I'm trying to adapt for my program.  I have it working as I wish, but I was unsure a little on what these numbers mean in this case.  Can anybody shed any light on what the 0x01 etc mean.

```
    private const int MouseEventMove = 0x01;
    private const int MouseEventLeftDown = 0x02;
    private const int MouseEventLeftUp = 0x04;
    private const int MouseEventRightDown = 0x08;
    private const int MouseEventRightUp = 0x10;
    private const int MouseEventAbsolute = 0x8000;
```

Thanks.

Comment: These are the windows messages codes. Windows will send these codes if the related events to them happen.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake. They're flags right? As @Hans Passant is said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are **Flag** enumerations.
They are each given a value in powers of 2, so for any combined value, there will be no ambiguity about which of the flags are set.

From MSDN:

> Flags enumerations are used for masking bit fields and doing bitwise
>   comparisons. They are the correct design to use when multiple
>   enumeration values can be specified at the same time.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229062.aspx

In your particular case it seems that the enumeration describes what type of mouse event is occurring.

Edit: As Hans points out, this is not technically an enumeration, but a group of `const int` definitions, though for all practical purposes I feel it serves as an enumeration - giving a human readable label for an integral value. Is there a more suitable name for this?

Comment: They actually are not.  The values are declared with a #define in the Windows SDK header.  Thus the translation to *const int*.

Comment: @Hans - you're right about that, though for all functional purposes they serve as an enumeration. What would you call such a group of const ints?

Answer (score 3):

Those are the values of the MOUSEEVENTF flags you pass to the [mouse_event()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646260%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) Windows api function.  The flag values are declared in the WinUser.h Windows SDK header file.  As noted in the linked MSDN article you shouldn't be using this function anymore.

Visit pinvoke.net to get the proper declaration for SendInput().

Comment: Hi Hans.  Yes, the code i'm using does make use of the SendInput method but it still requires these flags.  Thanks for the advice on the further reading material.